# Entropy of mixing formula

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Could someone give me a proof for the entropy of mixing formula,
$$\Delta S_{{mix}}=-R(x_{1}\ln x_{1}+x_{2}\ln x_{2}),$$
with
$$x_i= \frac{N_i}{N} = \frac{V_i}{V} \ \ ?$$

Comment: For ideal gases the mixing entropy was found by Gibbs, "On equilibrium of heterogeneous substances": he used Dalton's law. On Wikipedia you can find also the modern "statistical mechanics" derivation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_mixing .  See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78860/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705599/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261522/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12627/226902

Comment: Start with Vant Hoff Equation( ∆G = -RT*lnK) Use the Equilibrium constant with appropriate variables, remember to use dH = TdS and also take the difference of free energies before and after mixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Herbert B. Callen - Thermodynamics And An Introduction To Thermostatistics-Wiley (1985)* has two proofs, one more theoretical and the other one is a simple thought experiment. The first start at page 66 in the paragraph *3-4 THE SIMPLE IDEAL GAS AND
MULTICOMPONENT SIMPLE IDEAL GASES*, the second one right after at page 69.